# Java Webservice java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws, cxf, classcastexception

I am using Maven, CXF 2.2.7, JBoss 4.2.3 and JRE 1.5 **Updated**

I have a Webservice that I can see on the server by using the URL myURL/myService?wsdl

I am trying to develop a web app to ping that webservice by calling this in my bean:

MyWebService webservice = new MyWebService();

However, it dies and throws the following error, which is very vague:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:81)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.otherservice.webservice.MyWebServiceService.<init>(MyWebService.java:44)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at net.myservice.beans.MyBean.getMyServiceSoap(MyBean.java:109)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at net.myservice.beans.MyBean.ack(MyBean.java:240)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:131)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.jasper.el.JspMethodExpression.invoke(JspMethodExpression.java:68)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:77)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:95)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:383)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:450)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:759)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:97)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:266)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:132)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:301)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at net.faces.filters.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:84)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
09:25:59,450 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

I am hoping someone has seen this exception before and can help me.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2_02</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-b19</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomahawk</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>20040218.194635</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.locale4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>locale4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.odysseus.juel</groupId>
        <artifactId>juel</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a classloader issue where multiple classloaders are loading the jaxws api classes. My main thought would be to check the classloaders and wars and endorsed areas and such for any of the jaxws-api jars and make sure it's only found in one place.

Comment: I added my dependency list to my above post.  Only 3 jars are in the endorsed folder of my jboss 4.2.3 directory.  I have a few jboss-jaxws.jar files in the server/default/lib folder, but if I pull them out jboss blows up.  Only references I could find to those jaxws api classes.

Comment: I had to pull out of the server/default/lib directory jboss-jaxws.jar, jboss-jaxws-ext.jar and the entire jbossws.sar directory in the server/default/deploy to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked around this JBoss classloader issue by using the following code:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Service;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException;
import javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceDelegate;
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.BusFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl;

Bus bus = BusFactory.newInstance().createBus();
ServiceDelegate service = new ServiceImpl(bus, url, portName, null);
Dispatch<Source> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName, Source.class, Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
```